# Parse dynamic string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this :

```
var str = "[x] + [y] - [z]"
```

I want an array: 
`arr[0] = x , arr[1]=y` ...and so on.

My string can contain multiple operators and fields

Comment: What is your ultimate aim by parsing the string to array?

Comment: @Rajesh, have you read 'Be nice' policy?? Probably he's just trying something out. Sarcasm wouldnt help

Comment: @Rajesh, how can you  be sure that he didnt try or research at first? May be he was just stuck. happens to all. can you find a duplicate question somewhere?

Comment: Please be more descriptive. Try to provide your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a regex to replace the arithmatic operations and '['. Then split the string by ']' to get an array.

PS: slice(0, -1) is remove the last item from the array which is just a "".

```js
 var str = "[x] + [y] - [z]";
 
var arr = str.replace(/[+-/*//[ ]/g,'').split("]").slice(0, -1);;

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: i have a string like this "[numA1-E1]+[SalineLotNumberQ2-P1]" .
The regex gives arr[0] = numA1E1  whereas i want arr[0] = numA1-E1.
If you can help out on this?

Comment: Please create an new question.

Comment: Cant create that. It will be the same question. I just want the minus sign to be not removed when it is in a [ ].

Comment: I have posted a new question. Please give the answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49190853/regex-for-parsing-not-working-properly

Comment: Check my answer on the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49191768/6654503