# Regex for parsing not working properly

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this

```
str = "[numA1-E1]+[SalineLotNumberQ2-P1]-[numericP1-A1]"
```

The regex gives

```
arr[0] = numA1E1 
arr[1] = SalineLotNumberQ2P1
arr[2] = numericP1A1
```

whereas i want

```
arr[0] = numA1-E1 
arr[1] = SalineLotNumberQ2-P1
arr[2] = numericP1-A1
```

**If i remove minus from my regex, it will give arr[2]= -numericP1-A1**

If you can help out on this?

Currently my regex is

```
str.replace(/[+-/*//[ ]/g,'').split("]").slice(0, -1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out.
First regex removes the ]...[ & adds | as a separator, then ] and then [. Once you are done with this, split by |

```js
str = "[numA1-E1]+[SalineLotNumberQ2-P1]-[numericP1-A1]";

arr = str.replace(/(\].*?\[)/g, '|').replace(/[\]]/, "").replace(/[\[]/, "").split("|")

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Awesome dude !!

Comment: if i have str = "[App Version]+4+[Number 1 Q1-P3]".... i  want 
arr[0] = App Version
arr[1] = Number 1 Q1-P3

Comment: Please reply @ivp

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using regex. First, you need to split it using **]** and remove **+**. And then you have to map the array to remove sign **-** from starting of the string.

**Here is the code:**

```
    var str = "[numA1-E1]+[SalineLotNumberQ2-P1]-[x-y]";
    var arr =str.replace(/[+/*//[ ]/g,'').split("]").slice(0, -1);
    arr = arr.map(function(item){
       return item.replace(/^-/, '')
    });
    console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Pleasure!! Keep asking!!

Answer (score 0):

Just don't `replace` **-** with empty string:

```
str.replace(/[+/*//[ ]/g,'').split("]").slice(0, -1);
```

```js
const str = "[numA1-E1]+[SalineLotNumberQ2-P1]" ;
const result = str.replace(/[+/*//[ ]/g,'').split("]").slice(0, -1); /* don't include "-" in regex for replace method, so it stays in result */
console.log(result[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove - from regex

```
 var str = "[numA1-E1]+[SalineLotNumberQ2-P1]";
    var abc =str.replace(/[+/*//[ ]/g,'').split("]").slice(0, -1);
    console.log(abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "[numA1-E1]+[SalineLotNumberQ2-P1]-[numericP1-A1]" 
m = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]+', s)
```

m should be `['numA1-E1', 'SalineLotNumberQ2-P1', 'numericP1-A1']`

edit: This is python, js regex works similarly

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
str="[numA1-E1]+[SalineLotNumberQ2-P1]-[numericP1-A1]";

array=str.match(/\[[^\]]*\]/g);  //here it will make array of string(that is sur rounded by [ and ]) 
array=array.map(x=>x.replace(/\[|\]/g,'')); //here replace [ and ] to ''

console.log(array);
```

**Regex explanation**

`\[[^\]]*\]` below

```
\[     ---> will match '['
[^\]]* ---> will match any string which does not contain ']'
\]     ---> will match ']'
```

`\[|\]` will match '[' or ']'

Answer (score 0):

A bit simpler solution, match all the chars that are between `[ ]` and remove the brackets.

```js
const str = "[numA1-E1]+[SalineLotNumberQ2-P1]-[numericP1-A1]";
const result = str.match(/\[([^\]]+)\]/g).map(item => item.substr(1, item.length - 2))

console.log(result);
```